# FullFragging example

Tags: mvvmcross

Is there a FullFragging example with an ActionBar?  I don't want to use the support library and I'm having a hard time translating my app from straight up Android to mvvmcross with full fragging.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Possible duplicate of [this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474183/does-mvvmcross-support-actionbar)

MvxFragments are based on the support library so that it works back to Android 2.2.  In the end it looks just like the same thing.  I ended up implementing this and it basically just exists in the action bar.  You have to set up the tabhost and etc in the xml but I would look at this [example.](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/3fb27dfc5f59a10ca3bbe9a0e2b70f4ecd09711c/Fragments)